# Subsetting SparkR DataFrame based on column values matching another DataFrame's column values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I have two SparkR DataFrames, `newHiresDF` and `salesTeamDF`. I want to get a subset of `newHiresDF` based on the values of `newHiresDF$name` that are in `salesTeamDF$name`, but I can't figure out a way to do this. Below is the code for my attempts.

```
#Create DataFrames
newHires <- data.frame(name = c("Thomas", "George", "Bill", "John"),
    surname = c("Smith", "Williams", "Brown", "Taylor"))
salesTeam <- data.frame(name = c("Thomas", "Bill", "George"),
    surname = c("Martin", "Clark", "Williams"))
newHiresDF <- createDataFrame(newHires)
salesTeamDF <- createDataFrame(salesTeam)
display(newHiresDF)

#Try to subset newHiresDF based on name values in salesTeamDF
#All of the below result in errors
NHsubset1 <- filter(newHiresDF, newHiresDF$name %in% salesTeamDF$name)
NHsubset2 <- filter(newHiresDF, intersect(select(newHiresDF, 'name'), 
    select(salesTeamDF, 'name')))
NHsubset3 <- newHiresDF[newHiresDF$name %in% salesTeamDF$name,] #This is how it would be done in R

#What I'd like NHsubset to look like:
    name  surname
1 Thomas    Smith
2 George Williams
3   Bill    Brown
```

PySpark code will also work if you prefer that.

Comment: Just realized this is a near duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095208/subset-dataframe-based-on-matching-values-in-another-dataframe-pyspark-1-6-1 but that hasn't been answered either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution that seems simple in hindsight: just use `merge`.

```
NHsubset <- merge(newHiresDF, select(salesTeamDF, 'name'))
```